# How can I be seeing UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone when my app is in the Notification Center?

Tags: ios, notifications, uilocalnotification, nsnotificationcenter

I have a user with iOS 5.1.1 who is reporting that my app is not allowing him to set notifications even though he's put it in Notification Center.  He's sent me a screenshot that shows he's clearly put it in the Notification Center.  But if the app is not allowing him to set a notification, it's because this code came back with notificationIssue == YES:

```
BOOL notificationIssue = NO;
UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
if (types == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone) notificationIssue = YES;
```

I don't have access to his device, of course, so I can't investigate further myself, but I wonder if anyone has any ideas how the app could clearly be in Notification Center, with Badges, Sounds, and Alerts enabled, and yet still fail this test?

I can't reproduce this, and I haven't heard of this issue from anyone else.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, but with a development APNS certificate. I've tried turning off notifications and turning them back on but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

`enabledRemoteNotificationTypes` only references the "Alert Style" section in Settings->Notifications.

If you set that to "None" and leave everything on, you will still get a `UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone` and your `notificationIssue` would be a `YES`. By the same token, the user could disable notifications and set the "Alert Style" to banner and your `notificationIssue` would be set to `NO`.

It begs the real question... how do I find out the rest of the information? Right now, you don't. Apple didn't give us the API to query this information. My personal suggestion is to [report it to Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com) and request API. This is how we let them know we want API to access this information.

Answer (score 1):

I have also come across this scenario (`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes]` returns `UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone` even though app is in notification centre and has 'Alert Style' of 'banners').

I found that toggling that 'alert style to 'none' then back to 'banners' in the notification centre fixed the problem on my test device.